# Evaluation of lists: AvgP@K and R@K are they same?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, precision-recall

My goal is to understand Average `Precision at K`, and `Recall at K`. I have two lists, one is predicted and other is actual (ground truth)

lets call these two lists as predicted and actual. Now I want to do `precision@k` and `recall@k`.

Using python I implemented Avg precision at K as follows:

```
def apk(actual, predicted, k=10):
    """
    Computes the average precision at k.

    This function computes the average precision at k between two lists of items.

    Parameters
    ----------
    actual: list
            A list of elements that are to be predicted (order doesn't matter)
    predicted : list
            A list of predicted elements (order does matter)
    k: int, optional

    Returns
    -------
    score : double
            The average precision at k over the input lists

    """
    if len(predicted) > k:
        predicted = predicted[:k]

    score = 0.0
    num_hits = 0.0

    for i,p in enumerate(predicted):
        if p in actual and p not in predicted[:i]:
            num_hits += 1.0
            score += num_hits / (i + 1.0)

    if not actual:
        return 1.0
    if min(len(actual), k) == 0:
        return 0.0
    else:
        return score / min(len(actual), k)
```

lets assume that our predicted has 5 strings in following order: 
`predicted = ['b','c','a','e','d'] and`actual = ['a','b','e']`since we are doing @k would the precision@k is same as`recall@k`? If not how would I do`recall@k`

If I want to do `f-measure (f-score)` what would be the best route to do for above mention list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess, you've already checked [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval#Average_precision). Based on its formula, the 3rd and the biggest one (after the words 'This finite sum is equivalent to:'), let's see at your example for each iteration:

1. i=1 p = 1
2. i=2 rel = 0
3. i=3 p = 2/3
4. i=4 p = 3/4
5. i=5 rel = 0

So, avp@4 = avp@5 = (1 + 0.66 + 0.75) / 3 = 0.805; avp@3 = (1 + 0.66) / 3 and so on.

Recall@5 = Recall@4 = 3/3 = 1; Recall@3 = 2/3; Recall@2 =Recall@1 = 1/3

Below is the code for precision@k and recall@k. I kept your notation, while it seems to be more common to use `actual` for observed/returned value and `expected` for ground truth (see for example JUnit defaults).

```
def precision(actual, predicted, k):
    act_set = set(actual)
    pred_set = set(predicted[:k])
    result = len(act_set & pred_set) / float(k)
    return result

def recall(actual, predicted, k):
    act_set = set(actual)
    pred_set = set(predicted[:k])
    result = len(act_set & pred_set) / float(len(act_set))
    return result
```

Comment: Hi! Are you sure this is the correct implementation?
Here is the example:
```y_true = np.array([1,1,1,1])
preds = np.array([1,1,1,1])

precision(y_true, preds, k=3) output: 0.3333```